# Python datetime.datetime with psycopg2.dt.fixedoffsettimezone to pandas timestamp with timezone

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, timezone, psycopg2

I'm using PostgreSQL to store timestamps with time zone information. When querying this from python, using pandas.read_sql(), these timestamps are returned as datetime.datetime objects with tzinfo of psycopg2.dt.fixedoffsettimezone(...). Is there any way of returning or efficiently converting these datetimes as pandas timestamps, so that they can be easily manipulated using pandas functionality?